# How JVM determines datatype of primitive variables?

Tags: java

I came to know char type takes 16 bits and short type also takes 16 bits then how jvm will determine which type is what? JVM must have dependent on something else to determine the type of variable than the size of type stored in memory

Please let me know what is the architecture inside jvm that is helpful in finding the primitive data type of variable.

Comment: "*how jvm will determine which type is what*" you type it. If you type `char c` its a `char`, if you type `short c`, its a `short`. No need to further complicate it.

Comment: See [2.2: Data Types in the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.2): *The Java Virtual Machine expects that nearly all type checking is done prior to run time, typically by a compiler, and does not have to be done by the Java Virtual Machine itself. Values of primitive types need not be tagged or otherwise be inspectable to determine their types at run time, or to be distinguished from values of reference types. ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the data types and operations are strictly defined by the Java virtual machine specification.

From Oracle documentation:

> The Java Virtual Machine expects that nearly all type checking is done prior to run time, typically by a compiler, and does not have to be done by the Java Virtual Machine itself. Values of primitive types need not be tagged or otherwise be inspectable to determine their types at run time or to be distinguished from values of reference types.

Comment: Funny thing thing that your answer has the exact same quote as that one comment there.